# Implementing the Options pattern with a class injected during ConfigureServices - AddScoped

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a small class to obtain a series of information about my user on several of my MVC applications. A minimal reproducible example would be:

```cs
public class InformationGetter
    {
        public string GetUserInformation(string connectionStr, string storedProcedureName, int userId)
        {
            // Do SQL work
            return info;
        }
}
```

I'm injecting it on the ConfigureServices step using

```cs
services.AddScoped<InformationGetter>
```

And then in my classes I simply call it from the DI.

Now, obviously the connectionStr and storedProcedure only changes per application but right now I'm passing it as parameter.

I've tried to make those parameters public and configure it using services.Configure but when I call it from my controllers, I get null values.

```cs
            services.AddOptions();
            services.Configure<InformationGetter>(options =>
            {
                options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("Model").GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
                options.StoredProcedureName = "prInformationGetter";
            });
```

I'm not sure if the reason why this is failing it's because I'm missing an interface on my original class or am I failing to understand this concept.

I've also thought on doing something like `services.AddInformationGetter(options => {})` but my understanding is that this pattern is to implement middlewares and not DI specifically.

I tried checking the documentation (learn.microsoft.com) but I got even more confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be misunderstanding of the concepts involved.

`Configure<TOption>` will register `IOptions<TOptions>`. There are now two separate registrations in your example.

Once when you register the class

```
services.AddScoped<InformationGetter>()
```

and the other when you register the options.

Do the following

```
//..

services.AddOptions();

//Adds IOptions<InformationGetter>
services.Configure<InformationGetter>(options => {
    options.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("Model").GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
    options.StoredProcedureName = "prInformationGetter";
});

//Adds InformationGetter but gets it from the registered options
services.AddScoped<InformationGetter>(sp => 
    sp.GetRequiredService<IOptions<InformationGetter>>().Value
);

//...
```

The scoped registration will use the factory delegate to extract the options registered and return the desired type.

```
public class InformationGetter {
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string StoredProcedureName { get; set; }
    //...

    public string GetUserInformation(int userId) {
        // Do SQL work
        return info;
    }
}
```

`InformationGetter` looks like a service.

I would suggest refactoring to follow a more Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and Separation of Concerns (Soc) design.

```
//Needed by InformationGetter to perform its function
public class InformationGetterOptions {
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string StoredProcedureName { get; set; }
}

//abstraction of InformationGetter
public interface IInformationGetter {
    string GetUserInformation(int userId);
}

//implementation.
public class InformationGetter : IInformationGetter{  
    private readonly InformationGetterOptions options;

    public InformationGetter(InformationGetterOptions options) {
        this.options = options;
    }

    public string GetUserInformation(int userId) {

        //use values in options to connect

        // Do SQL work
        return info;
    }
}
```

I would have avoid options pattern altogether and just registered the class using the delegate factory, extracting what I need from configuration. That way your code is not tightly coupled to framework concerns like `IOptions`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    //...

    InformationGetterOptions options = new InformationGetterOptions {
        ConnectionString = Configuration.GetSection("Model").GetSection("ConnectionString").Value;
        StoredProcedureName = "prInformationGetter";
    };
    services.AddSingleton(options);
    services.AddScoped<IInformationGetter, InformationGetter>();

    //...
}
```

Now `IInformationGetter` can be injected where needed and have all the necessary dependencies to perform its function.

Comment: So if Configure already registers the class, do I still have to do AddScoped or wouldn't be necessary?

Comment: Configure registers an IOptions that wraps the class. I would have avoid options altogether and just registered the class using the delegate factory, extracting what I need from configuration

Comment: Could you update with your recommendation as well? I'm learning so seeing the differences between all options would help me understand better what I'm doing.

Comment: @Narshe check update. Anything additional would have to be done in a new question as it will stray away from the original scope of the question.

Comment: Thanks a million for the update and recommendations. That made my learning journey way better :)